# New Files Lost After Git Rebase

Tags: xcode, git, rebase

I created a couple new files locally. During the rebase there were merge conflicts, and I think accidentally deleted the new files before completing the rebase.

Here's my problem - when I checkout to old commits via `git reflog`, there are references to my new files, but the files do not exist on my computer. Xcode shows the file names in red, and when I manually check the directory there is nothing there.

Does anybody know how to retrieve my code? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you had committed a version of the project file that referred to the files, but had not committed the files themselves.  If that's the case, then git does not have them.  You'd have to refer to any backups you might have.

Comment: Is that even possible - I thought you couldn't start a rebase with uncommitted changes?

Comment: If you have unstaged changes to tracked files, git will resist starting a rebase.  If you have untracked files, git doesn't care.